# How to prevent an action from running if json payload is too large

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to limit the size of the json payload that is http posted to my action.

How can I limit the size to 1 MB?

If the limit is exceeded, can I return a custom JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

When using body parsers, you can specify the `maxLength`: cf [api](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.BodyParsers$parse$@json(maxLength:Int):play.api.mvc.BodyParser[play.api.libs.json.JsValue])

```
val maxSize = 1024 * 1024 // 1 MB
def jsonAction = Action(parse.json(maxSize)) { request =>
  val json = request.body
  ...
}
```

If you want to send a custom http error, you can extend the default http error handler. See the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaErrorHandling#Extending-the-default-error-handler)

```
override def onOtherClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String): Future[Result] = {
  if (statusCode == Status.REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE) {
    Future.successful(Results.EntityTooLarge(Json.obj("error" -> "too large")))
  } else {
    super.onOtherClientError(request, statusCode, message)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12599047/900130), you can check the `Content-Length` header:

```
request.headers.get(play.api.http.HeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH)
```

Check if it's larger than 1 MB and return whatever kind of response you want. Preferably a 413 Payload too large, as pointed out by the other answer.